# pdf sent to client to download returns blank pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf

Im using html-pdf to generate a pdf document in the server, im then exporting that to the frontend to be downloaded. The PDF generates correctly on the server, however on the client all that is downloaded is a pdf document with the correct amount of pages, but no content. Im saving the file locally to the server, and if i pull that document up on my browser it indeed is formatted how i want it to be formatted, everything is correct. but no matter what i do, all the client receives is several blank pages.

i've read in several SO posts about `byte-shaving` and that the content isnt being received correctly because of incorrect formatting (i.e. the document is in `utf-8` or some such thing) and needs to be in `base64` i was successful in creating a base64 document (not shown here) but then that created a new problem in `Document not readable` when the document was downloaded, it then also created a problem with the server document in that it was now blank, and had no content.

im at my wits end, the document is correct but i cannot receive it correctly in the client, im hoping some fresh eyes can make sense of what i cant see.

server

```
const pdf = require("html-pdf");
const asyncHandler = require("../middleware/async");
const { error: errorHandler } = require("../middleware/error");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const Deck = require("../models/deckModel");
const DeckListTemp = require("../templates/DeckListTemp");
const Dynamic = require("../models/dynamicModel");

/**
 * @description Generate PDF document of deck list
 * @param       {Number} deckId - Deck ID
 * @returns     {String} - PDF document
 * @author      Austin Howard
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @since       1.0.0
 * @date        2022-5-30
 *
 */
module.exports = asyncHandler(async (req, response, next) => {
  try {
    // find the deck
    const deck = await Deck.findById(req.params.deckId);
    // get the logo of the application
    const logo = await Dynamic.findOne({ type: "Logo" });
    // check to see if the deck and logo exist
    if (!deck || !logo) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "Cannot find deck or logo on Server",
      });
    }

    // need to sort cards by name
    await deck.cards.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    // console log one card so we can see what we're working with
    // console.log(deck.cards[0]);
    // pass the deck to the template
    const html = DeckListTemp(deck, logo.value);
    // set up the html-to-pdf converter

    // we need to url encode the deck name in case there is any special characters
    // basically we just want to make sure any forward slashes are not in the deck name
    // so we replace them with a space
    // since any forward slash would cause the pdf to go to a subdirectory
    // and we don't want that
    deck.deck_name = deck.deck_name.replace(/\//g, " ");

    // we need to make the pdf a promise so we can await its creation
    await Promise.all([
      // create the pdf
      pdf
        .create(html, {
          encoding: "UTF-8",
          format: "A3",
          border: {
            top: "1in",
            right: "1in",
            bottom: "1in",
            left: "1in",
          },
        })
        .toFile(
          `${__dirname}../../../public/pdf/${deck.deck_name
            .substring(0, 50)
            .replace(/\//g, " ")}.pdf`,
          async function (err, res) {
            try {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                console.log(`Document created for ${deck.deck_name}`);
                // create a readable stream from the file
                console.log(
                  `creating readable stream from ${deck.deck_name
                    .substring(0, 50)
                    .replace(/\//g, " ")}.pdf`
                );
                // pipe the readable stream to the response

                // need to create a buffer then decode that buffer as base64 so that we can send it to the client
                const buffer = await Buffer.from(
                  await fs.readFileSync(
                    `${__dirname}../../../public/pdf/${deck.deck_name
                      .substring(0, 50)
                      .replace(/\//g, " ")}.pdf`
                  )
                );

                response.setHeader(
                  "Content-disposition",
                  `attachment; filename=${deck.deck_name}.pdf`
                );
                await response.sendFile(
                  path
                    .join(
                      `${__dirname}../../../public/pdf/${deck.deck_name
                        .substring(0, 50)
                        .replace(/\//g, " ")}.pdf`
                    )
                    .toString("base64"),
                  (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log("downloading");
                    }
                  }
                );
                // fs.unlinkSync(
                //   `${__dirname}../../../public/pdf/${deck.deck_name
                //     .substring(0, 50)
                //     .replace(/\//g, " ")}.pdf`
                // );
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
          }
        ),
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: `Server Error - ${error.message}`,
    });
  }
});
```

client

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  DECK_PREVIEW_REQUEST,
  DECK_PREVIEW_SUCCESS,
} from "../../constants/deckConstants";
import { setAlert } from "../../utils/alert";

export const generatePdf = (deck) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: DECK_PREVIEW_REQUEST });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/force-download",
      },
    };
    const data = await axios.post(`/api/deck/${deck._id}/pdf`, config);
    // console.log(data);
    // Create blob link to download
    // const blob = new Blob([data.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
    console.log(data.data);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([data.data], { type: "application/octet-stream" })
    );
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", `${deck.deck_name}.pdf`);

    // Append to html link element page
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    // Start download
    link.click();

    // Clean up and remove the link
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    dispatch({ type: DECK_PREVIEW_SUCCESS });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    dispatch(setAlert(`problem generating pdf ${error}`, "danger"));
  }
};
```